# Designing email signatures for Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook

I created this email signature template that needs to be used in Outlook. It looks great in browsers but Outlook completely messes it up. I'm not sure what I'm missing

This is the exact file I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <style>
.sContainer {
    border: solid 1px black;
    widows: 200px;
    width: 350px;
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 8pt;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
}

.sHeader {
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: solid #FFC300 2px;
}
.sHeader .name {
    font-size: 14pt;
}
.linebreak{
    color: yellow;
}
.sBody{
    width:100%;
}
.sLogo{
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    float: left;
}
.sContent{
    padding-left: 15px;
    float: left;
}
.name,.position{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.sContent a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #000 !important;
}

.sContent p {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.highlight{
    color:#FFC300;
}

.sLogo img{
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="sContainer">
            <div class="sHeader">
                <p class="name">FULL NAME</p>
                <p class="position">POSITION | POSITION (FR)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="sBody">
                <div class="sLogo">
                    <img src="http://bgdistribution.ca/wp-content/themes/bgdistribution/images/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
                </div>
                <div class="sContent">  
                    <a class="sEmail" href="mailto:EMAILADDRESS"><p>EMAIL ADDRESS</p></a>
                    <p class="sCell">C:(514) XXX-XXXX</p>
                    <p class="sTelephone">T:(514) XXX-XXXX</p>  
                    <a href="www.bgdistribution.ca" class="sUrl"><p>www.<span class="highlight">bgdistribution</span>.ca</p></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Luz4u/

Answer (score 1):

Outlook does not support stylesheets. All styles must be declared inline, and even then styling is limited.

See: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: According to the link, it supports the style tag in the header and link tags (stylesheets).

Comment: Omg I can't set width on a div tag?! This is impossible I give up.

Comment: Believe it or not, it's TABLEs all over again when it comes to Outlook email layouts.

Comment: Ohhh if I can set the width on a table cell that would be fine. Hmm I'll try again but this dumb

Comment: Outlook actually uses the MS Word HTML rendering engine, which is complete garbage.

Comment: Any idea how I could recreate what I have using tables? I don't see how the image would fit in unless I have a nested table (if that's a thing)

Comment: I tried doing it like this, mind taking a look and seeing why it doesn't work? I don't really know how to work with tables: http://jsfiddle.net/Luz4u/3/

Comment: You can certainly nest tables and that is actually how many marketing emails are built. You will need to using inline styles and hard-code all of the dimensions for everything to work. See:http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2491/tables-in-html-emails-nesting/

Answer (score 0):

Use word to create the signature. Save as HTML, remove the html code that word adds and use this template. It will work, I have done this